# Can PN532 with Raspberry Pi send NDEF message to an Android phone with NFC?

Tags: android, c++, raspberry-pi, ndef, lib-nfc

I am currently working on a school project that includes NFC communication to send posters (or URL) from PN532 (connected to a Raspberry Pi) to an Android phone.

I have been looking for a library where I can implement SNEP/NPP in order to send an NDEF message to an Android phone, like "libllcp" from "libnfc".

However, when I run the "snep-server" example from the library, all I can do is receive data from the phone, but not sending data to it while no response is given by the phone when I run the "snep-client" example (the phone vibrated but no data is received).

Since I am only familiar with C++, I want to know whether I can send NDEF message with "libllcp" alone or is there a C/C++ based library which I can implement SNEP/NPP.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What controller you are using is far less important than how the chip is interfaced.  For example, if you are using the usual UART interface, then your platform is just another generic Linux and limiting the apparent scope to the pi would be counterproductive.

Comment: I am using UART to connect PN532 to the pi. But I'm sorry I don't really nderstand what you mean, what are your suggestions for me to achieve NDEF data exchage with android phone via SNEP?

Comment: I'm suggesting that this is a PN532 and Linux question, because those are things that define the options available to you, and not a Raspberry Pi question, because that is just another Linux platform in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I send some data from PN532 to an Android phone with the SNEP library. This is C++ code. It is on the [GitHub](https://github.com/Don/NDEF) site.

You should use Arduino for communicating with PN532.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.